# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

im learning C# (to develop for windows phone), and im trying to authenticate my user into Google's account. Im using this code:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#wp

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);
```

But, i dont know why, i can't use 'GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker'. I already installed all the references, and im using all the imports.

When i run my program, i got these two messages:

'The name 'CancellationToken' does not exist in the current context'

'The name 'GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker' does not exist in the current context'

[image: code]

[image: error]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To minimize my feedback cycle, i created a new windows phone project from the scratch, using windows phone OS 7.1 as my target OS version, then i executed these commands in package manager console:

```
pm> install-package google.apis -pre
pm> install-package google.apis.drive.v2 -pre
```

Then, in my MainPage.xaml.cs, i wrote these imports:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Threading;
```

And, finally i tried to simple call 'GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker' by IntelliSense, but i couldn`t find it. So, as my last test, i wrote 'GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker' to see if Visual Studio point my error and suggest any solution, but VS only gave me the options to create a new class or new type.

Last but not least, im using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone, dont know if it affects...

**UPDATE2:**

When i expanded Google.Apis.Auth in Object Browser, i couldn't find the missing class(GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker), it looks like my installation didn't went well...

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

According to NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis), Google.Apis is compatible with Windows Phone 7.5 and 8.0. As i said up there, im using windows phone OS 7.1 as my target OS version, i updated my 7.1 SDK, but couldn't find 7.5 sdk, so, should i use 7.8? keep in mind that i need to develop for windows phone 7.X

Answer (score 6):

If you are building a "portable class library" project, like I was, you may need to manually add a reference to

**Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices**

I don't know why it is left out when adding google apis to a "Portable Class Library", but that's what solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use these:

in package manager.

```
pm> install-package google.apis -pre
pm> install-package google.apis.drive.v2 -pre
```

then include:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Threading;
```

Comment: That doesnt work :( but now Visual Studio gave me the options to generate class / new type for GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker

Comment: Check for namespace issues the above answer should work.

Comment: I couldn'd find any namespace issues, just updated my question with some details about my project, hope it help..

Answer (score 2):

I had the error GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker not found and I fixed by removing the reference to:
Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices from my project and
Going to the folder where I had all google api assemblies and added 
....\packages\Google.Apis.Auth.1.8.1\lib\net40\Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll

To the project. I believe I had the wrong assembly.