# Xamarin forms upload to google drive

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application I need to upload a zip file to google drive.Is it possible to do this using Xamarin forms application? Do I need to implement this in each platform using dependency services? Please give me a proper suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine you'd have to create a [REST](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/) service to make use of the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), of course you'd have to manage [authentication](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use Google's C#-based API Nuget, they support PCL-based projects and the API contains Google Drive support:

#### `Xamarin.Forms`:

```
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
```

#### `Xamarin.Android`:

```
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.16.0"    targetFramework="monoandroid60"` />
```

#### `Xamarin.iOS`:

```
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

#### From Google's Drive Sample:

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Drive.Sample";
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("client_secrets.json",
    System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
}

// Create the service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
});

await UploadFileAsync(service);
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v3

Comment: I couldn't find Google.Apis.Auth in the package

Comment: Could you share any sample project?

Comment: I couldn't find GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456668/googlewebauthorizationbroker-not-found

Comment: Google's .NET client does not support Xamarin. See: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1468 and https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-arent-unity-xamarin-or-uwp-supported

Comment: @Mr.Yeah The OP question is about uploading to GDrive and it does work, they are .NetStd-based : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3 After 3 years I still use it.

Comment: @SushiHangover Then I don't get why Google explicitly says that it's incompatible with Xamarin.

Comment: @Mr.Yeah The Auth portion of their Drive .Net solution is natively attached to Windows, but it is just OAuth2 so you can roll your own. All their APIs (iOS|Android|.Net|...) use their underlaying REST (which is an option to use directly also).