# How to integrate Google Drive,DropBox, iCloud in xamarin.Form (Portable)?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, integration

I am using Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Cross-platform having two projects Android and iOS.

I want to integrate Google Drive, Dropbox, iCloud in my project. Please suggest me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer a below question in `StackOverflow` to integrate the Google Drive, Dropbox and iClound in your project.

Google Drive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233810/4025613
Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs
iCloud: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/ (You have to do some native code for this as iCloud will not support Android.)

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried for google drive but it does not work. When I am using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker. Error Occur - GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker  does not exist in the current context. I install nuget - google.apis,google.apis.auth. Do am I missing something

Comment: you need to install packages in all projects (Portable, Android and iPhone)

Comment: I install packages in all project, still getting same error